# Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, коллекции

У меня есть запрос:

```
$trains = Train::with('trips')
            ->whereIn('id', [1, 2])
            ->pluck('id', 'name')
            ->toArray();
```

Использую pluck и toArray, чтобы сразу достать id и name в виде массива.
Но есть проблема. Достаёт эти данные в виде name - ключ, а id - значение
А мне нужно, чтобы id и name были под одним ключом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Select (id, name)->get()->toArray()?

Comment: Да, спасибо, получилось :)

Answer (score 0):

Пример аналогичного запроса:

**Brand::query()->select('id', 'name')->get()->toArray()**

Результат:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 18
        [name] => 12341234123
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [name] => 41234124
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => Chemical Guys
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Festool
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [name] => Gyeon
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через такой запрос:

```
$trains = Train::with('trips')
            ->whereIn('id', [1, 2])
            ->select('id', 'name')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```